# How to tell if an object is linked with another blend?

Tags: python

Is there any way I can check if an object is linked from another Blend file via bpy? I need to do this for xrefs on something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for all sorts of variable names in the reference, 'link', 'blend', etc. I figured out that `object.library` was what I was looking for. It will return `None` if it's not from a library, otherwise it will return a `bpy.types.Library`

https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bpy.types.Library.html#bpy.types.Library